# Set Find my Friends so it shows my laptop location instead of my iPhone location?

Tags: icloud, macos, find-my-friends

Find my Friends currently shows my iPhone location. I would like to change it so it shows my Mac location instead. I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Is this supported directly by Apple or a 3rd party tool or app?

Answer (score 2):

Sure - if Find My Mac (FMM) is enabled and your iCloud accounts match, then open the iPhone Find My Friends (FMF) app and then do the following:

1. Tap your icon / row that's pinned at the bottom of the screen
2. Select your Mac from the list below
3. If the Mac isn't showing on the Mac in System Preferences

   1. In sharing preference item, give your Mac a name that's different than any of the other names in iOS FMF
   2. In the Security preference item, be sure Location Services is enabled and that System Services is enabled for Find My Mac (FMM)
   3. In iCloud preference item, ensure you're signed in with the identical AppleID as on the iPhone
   4. Turn on Find My Mac (FMM) - look for any network errors or server errors that show up within 5 minutes or so of registering

At this point the Mac should be able to select itself or your other iOS devices should be able to select the Mac to report your location. Be sure you leave WiFi on and Bluetooth on for the Mac to have the best chance to get a correct location. Search this site if your Mac doesn't pull the correct or any location